# Excel formula for calculating columns by given row

Tags: excel-formula

Given a story problem:

A string of Christmas lights of 150 lights total (Could Be Infinite)
Two possible values for the lights 0=Off or 1=On
If the lights are initially all 0:
Person1 turns all the lights to 1:
Person2 turns lights 2,4,6,8,...150 to 0:
Person3 turns lights 3,6,9,12...150 to 1:
Person4 turns lights 4,8,12,16...150 to 0:
Continuing on for 150 people.

How would I express this in an excel formula?

Answer (score 0):

This needs an iterative approach. Go to File | Options | Formulas, set Workbook calculation to Manual, tick Enable Iterative Calculation and set Maximum iterations to 1.

Set the light numbers 1-150 in C2-C151 using fill series.

Put the following formula in B2 to iterate through the person numbers:-

```
=IF(A2,0,B2+1)
```

Put the following formula in D2 to find if the light in C2 will be switched on or off (the odd guys always switch ON, even guys switch OFF but only for lights which are an exact multiple of their person number):-

```
=IF(A$2,FALSE,IF(MOD(C2,B$2)=0,ISODD(B$2),D2))
```

Copy the formula down from D3 to D151.

I've also put a formula to display a text string "ON" or "OFF" in E2 but this is optional:-

```
=IF(D2,"ON","OFF")
```

To initialise it (there might be a neater way of doing this), type a '1' in A2.

There should be a 'Calculate' button at the bottom of the screen. Pressing this once should set all the lights 'OFF'

Type a '0' in A2. Now each time you press 'Calculate' it will simulate the action of the person whose number is displayed in B2.

Here's how it would look after Person 3 has had a go:-

[image]

If you want to see how it would look after all 150 have had a go, go back in to File | Options | Formula and set Maximum Iterations to 150.

Reset it as before and calculate.

Now it looks like this:-

[image]

The lights alternate - was this what you expected? For all the even lights, the most recent action was performed by an even guy so it's off, and vice-versa.

Or maybe you were thinking of the problem outlined in Matt Parker's book Things to Make and Do in the 4th Dimension. Here a succession of guards can lock and unlock cell doors with the same constraints except that they always turn a 0 (locked) into a 1 (unlocked) and a 1 into a 0 and it turns out that the ones that stay open are the ones with square numbers 1,4,9,16 ...

In this case the formula in column D would be

```
=IF(A$2,FALSE,IF(MOD(C2,B$2)=0,NOT(D2),D2))
```

and it would look like this:-

[image]